# How to hide / unhide section in Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview

I have a collection view, this collection view has 3 section:

**A**

**B**

**C**

Then I want to hide section B, then it will look like:

**A**

**C**

I have tried

```
collectionView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1))
```

but it crashes and says:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the
>   collection view after the update (3) must be equal to the number of
>   sections contained in the collection view before the update (3), plus
>   or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 1
>   deleted).'

Comment: You should remove section from your data source and reload collection view by calling `reloadData`. This will trigger `func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int` where your will return updated number of sections.

Comment: Because I want to reuse it then, I just want to hide / unhide section, so delete data section will not good in my case.

Comment: if you do like to delete the data source as the @fiks says , try to  make the section size be zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ask the collection view to update itself adding/removing sections or cells, you also have to update your delegate methods in order to return the right number.

I write some code on the fly, use it as a starting point to understand the concept:

```
var sections = 3
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return sections
}

func removeSectionOne() {
   sections = 2
   collectionView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: 1))
   // At this point the collection view will ask again for the number of sections and it will be updated
}
```

Comment: I think I need to have 2 arrays. One original array and one array for manipulating.

Comment: whatever works best for you. The thing is, you have two things to update: 1) The view model, so telling the collection view to add/remove sections/cells and 2) the data model that is used to shape the collection view. This two things must be coherent, so if you ask to remove a section, your dataSource methods should also return one section less.

Answer (score 1):

i have done same thing with tableview ,

first

```
   BOOL sectionIsOpen[2]; // Your Sections number (3 in your case )

   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView       {
       return self.arrMenu.count;
    }

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return ((sectionIsOpen[section]) ? [self   numberOfRowsInSection:section] : 0);
      }
```

`[self   numberOfRowsInSection:section` Contains the number of item in section

And when you need to hide pass section in method and

```
   for (NSInteger row = 0; row < [self numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row ++) {
        [indxPths addObject: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]
         ];
    }
    [self.tblMenu beginUpdates];
    if (open) {
        [self.tblMenu insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indxPths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }else{
        [self.tblMenu deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indxPths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
    sectionIsOpen[section] = open;
    [self.tblMenu endUpdates];
```

Hope it helps .....